# WebStorm use wrong @types definition file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using webstorm to write react page with react-router-dom@6.

react-router-dom@6 has built-in `index.d.ts` and @types/react-router-dom does not have a version higher than 6.

Normally, webstorm should use the built-in `index.d.ts` of react-router-dom. But webstorm automatically downloaded the wrong `@types/react-router-dom@5`

Just like in the following screenshots.

[image]

[image]

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

```
npx create-react-app <application-name>
```

cd 
npm start

> Click Create New Project on the Welcome screen or select File | New | Project from the main menu. The Create New Project Dialog opens.

In the left-hand pane, choose React.

In the right-hand pane:

Specify the path to the folder where the project-related files will be stored.

In the Node Interpreter field, specify the Node.js interpreter to use. Select a configured interpreter from the list or choose Add to configure a new one.

From the create-react-app list, select npx create-react-app.

Alternatively, for npm version 5.1 and earlier, install the create-react-app package yourself by running npm install --g create-react-app in the TerminalAlt+F12. When creating an application, select the folder where the create-react-app package is stored.

Optionally:

To use TSX instead of JSX, select the Create TypeScript project checkbox. WebStorm will generate .tsx files for your application and a tsconfig.json configuration file.

When you click Create, WebStorm generates a React-specific project with all the required configuration files and downloads the required dependencies. WebStorm also creates an npm start and JavaScript Debug configurations with default settings for running or debugging your application.

for more info please visit : [React-Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/react.html#creating_react_app_with_create_react_app)